# Why parameters in url disappear?

Tags: php, magento, url, nginx, parameters

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.0.1, and I made my own module for communication with mobile.
It was working fine on my local environment, so I applied our test server to test it.
But, parameters(strings next to 'checkout?') only disappear in our test server.
I mean the parameters already disappeared and the url only has **"dev-api-my-mobile.althea.kr/mobile/checkout"**.

```
dev-api-my-mobile.althea.kr/mobile/checkout?customerId=44789&tokenCode=7uNuLEdGDN9e1N8bKig3F2YW0XBLEGbT
```

So I tried to change to below url, finally my module caught this url.

http://dev-api-my-mobile.althea.kr/mobile/checkout?customerId%3D44789%26tokenCode%3D7uNuLEdGDN9e1N8bKig3F2YW0XBLEGbT%0D%0A

But, my module can't parse this parameters by default without any implementation.

I think the problem is related to nginx server setting.
Server seems like to remove strings next to '**mobile/checkout**' in url.

Do you have any similar experiences?